# Retrieving “venues managed” doesn't shows me all venues of a venue group I manage

Tags: api, foursquare

I try to call a list of venues managed. However, it doesn't show me all my managed vanues. I have a venue group with 4 venues. Only one of it shows up in this list (probably the oldest one).

How can I retrieve all venues of this group? There seems to be no /venuegroups/managed/ call...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the `/venuegroups/GROUP_ID` endpoint for complete information about a venue group.